# Is there any good textbook or notes on graph theory for undergraduate student?

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for such textbook or notes. Thanks in advance for sharing links or sites or any related questions!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, You can consider: [A first course in graph theory](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjouIKh3tfQAhWL7BQKHZvcAAcQFghAMAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.scribd.com%2Fbook%2F271576503%2FA-First-Course-in-Graph-Theory&usg=AFQjCNEVHqlxVsDfZr9D4Cw1br05sXqksw&sig2=GdD-Jf0IxO-eO3ruZ-j3tA)